# No definition found for Javascript page

Tags: javascript, html, function, calculator

I got an assignment to create a simple calculator using HTML and JavaScript.
I've built a simple HTML page with three inputs for two numbers and an operator.
I've also created a JS page with a function that will operate the calculator.

When I'm connecting the two pages using the `<script>` tag in the HTML page, when I check the JS page a short message pops up that says: "No definition found for CalculatorJS.js" (my JS page).

This is my HTML page code:

```
<head>  
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
    <h3>Enter two numbers and an operation in the right places below</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span><span> First Number</span> <span>Operation</span> <spaqn>Second        Number</span> </span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="firstNum">
    <span></span>

    <input type="text" id="operation">
    <span></span>

    <input type="text" id="secondNum">
    <span></span>

    <script src="CalculatorJS.js"></script>

    <button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>

</body>
```

And this is my JS page code:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
var operator = document.getElementById("operation").value;


var resulte = 0;
function Calculate(num1, operator,num2)
{
    if(operator == "+")
    {
        resulte = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if(operator == '-')
    {
        resulte = num1 - num2;
    }
    else if(operator == '*')
    {
        resulte = num1 * num2;
    }
    else if(operator == '/')
    {
        reulte = num1 / num2;
    }
    else{
        resulte = 'InValid Operator';
    }
    alert(resulte);
}

function Calculate2(num1, operator,num2)
{
    switch (operator) {
        case value: '+'
            return num1 + num2;
            break;
        case value: '-'
            return num1 - num2;
            break;
        case value: '*'
            return num1 * num2;
            break;
        case value: '/'
            return num1 / num2;
            break;

        default:
        return alert("InValid Charachter")
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there something I did in either of the pages that make the calculator not work?
And when I try to make a simple calculation like 1+1, 
I get the alert where I've written "InValid Operator".

Comment: num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value; num isnt live. It is copied. Therefore all changes are not kept

Comment: What exactly is giving you that error message? Why is your script tag all the way down the bottom instead of in the head with a check for whether the DOM is ready?

Comment: ok so how do i make num1 live? so that i can use it for what i want like the function?

* * in the html page i press ctrl and click on the src to the JS page and when i get to the JS page a blue message popsup and says that

* * *i've put the script all the way down because that's how my teacher taught us. i dont think he said something about putting it in the head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the page, the variables `num1`, `num2` and `operation` take null values. After that, when you input values and fire the `Calculate` function then these three variables get nothing because they are outside of the `Calculate` method, so it's showing "Invalid operator".

You have to declare `num1`, `num2` and `operation` inside the `Calculate` function. Then those three variables will get their values and will show the result. Check below:

```js
var resulte = 0;
  function Calculate()
  {
   var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
   var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNum").value);
   var operator = document.getElementById("operation").value;
   if(operator == "+")
   {
    resulte = num1 + num2;
   }
   else if(operator == '-')
   {
    resulte = num1 - num2;
   }
   else if(operator == '*')
   {
    resulte = num1 * num2;
   }
   else if(operator == '/')
   {
    resulte = num1 / num2;
   }
   else{
    resulte = 'InValid Operator';
   }
   alert(resulte);
  }

  function Calculate2(num1, operator,num2)
  {
   switch (operator) {
    case value: '+'
     return num1 + num2;
     break;
    case value: '-'
     return num1 - num2;
     break;
    case value: '*'
     return num1 * num2;
     break;
    case value: '/'
     return num1 / num2;
     break;

    default:
    return alert("InValid Charachter")
     break;
   }
  }
```

```html
<head>  
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
    <h3>Enter two numbers and an operation in the right places below</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span><span> First Number</span> <span>Operation</span> <span>Second        Number</span> </span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="firstNum">
    <span></span>

    <input type="text" id="operation">
    <span></span>

    <input type="text" id="secondNum">
    <span></span>

    <button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry ,you must parse num1 and num2 to int before calling the function

```
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("SecondNum").value);
```

Comment: ok so i understand that this will make the variables into number type or something like that.

but now how do i connect them to my function?
i did what you suggested but it still acts the same when i run it

Comment: only parsing does not solve the problem.this three variable must declare inside the calculate method.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
    <h3>Enter two numbers and an operation in the right places below</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span><span> First Number</span> <span>Operation</span>
    <spaqn>Second Number</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="firstNum">
        <span></span>

        <input type="text" id="operation">
        <span></span>
        <input type="text" id="secondNum">
        <span></span>

        <button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>

</body>
<script>
    var resulte = 0;

    function Calculate() {
        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNum").value);
        var operator = document.getElementById("operation").value;
        if (operator == "+") {
            resulte = num1 + num2;
        } else if (operator == '-') {
            resulte = num1 - num2;
        } else if (operator == '*') {
            resulte = num1 * num2;
        } else if (operator == '/') {
            resulte = num1 / num2;
        } else {
            resulte = 'InValid Operator';
        }

        alert(resulte);

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
    <h3>Enter two numbers and an operation in the right places below</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span><span> First Number</span> <span>Operation</span>
    <spaqn>Second Number</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="firstNum">
        <span></span>

        <input type="text" id="operation">
        <span></span>

        <input type="text" id="secondNum">
        <span></span>

        <button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>

        <script>
            var resulte = 0;

            function Calculate() {
                var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
                var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
                var operator = document.getElementById("operation").value;

                if (operator == "+") {
                    resulte = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
                } else if (operator == '-') {
                    resulte = Number(num1) - Number(num2);
                } else if (operator == '*') {
                    resulte = Number(num1) * Number(num2);
                } else if (operator == '/') {
                    if (Number(num2) == 0) {
                        resulte = 'Invalid Operation';
                        alert('Division by zero is undefined.')
                    } else {
                        resulte = Number(num1) / Number(num2);
                    }
                } else {
                    resulte = 'InValid Operator';
                }
                alert(resulte);
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The code is correct. so Why you down vote plz explain